# Spatial Data and Maps in .net 4.5

Tags: .net, dictionary, spatial, bing

I'm learning how to use the [System.Data.Spatial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.spatial.aspx) namespace in .NET I have a small app that saves and retrieves some spatial data from localdb. What I need now is show this data in some map in a web application. I don't know yet if Bing maps is the best choice but since is Microsoft tech I think the integration could be easier. What do I need to learn in order to be able to show this data in a map?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `SharpMap`,that's OpenSource  spatial libraries for .NET, you can find theses libraries on code plex.

http://www.codeplex.com/SharpMap